# Como filtrar a busca do Chrome DevTools pela extensão do arquivo?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

No DevTools do Chrome é possível realizar uma busca por alguma string nos arquivos que foram carregados apertando `Ctrl + Shift + F`.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é filtrar essa busca para que encontre apenas arquivos com uma determinada extensão, é possível faze-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de fuçar mais um pouco no Chrome, acabei descobrindo:

```
file:*.js string-para-procurar
```

Da para procurar em um arquivo especifico assim também

```
file:arquivo.js string-para-procurar
```